# Read BLOB from MySql to binary file in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework, blob

I want to read the WAV file stored as BLOB in the MySql using PHP. But I don't have any idea about it.

Please help me.....

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a simpliest query to select the data , put it into variable and use file_put_contents( ... ) or if you want to send it as downloadable file just use echo and make sure there no junk output and correct header

Comment: but can you show us the code please? because mine like this doesnt work  `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   $sound=$row['sound'];

   echo '<audio controls>';
      echo    '<source src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.$row['sound'].'">';
   echo '</audio>';`

Comment: You need to use base64_encode (Or something like this) on $row['sound'] - otherwise you are pulling raw data, while in data URL base64 is specified